# ejb timer service if first timer takes long can second timer start if first is executing

Tags: timer, ejb-3.0

I am a new bie to this timer feature, and i have some queries

There are timer scheduled to run after specific interval of time.

-can such a scenario happen that first timeout happened and its timeout method is executing, and if it takes duration more than the scheduled interval of timer, the timeout methood will be executed again even if the first one has not expired.

Answer (score 0):

According to the EJB specification there's nothing to stop this from happening.